# transformation on simple json array

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Im trying to update json array. If i have JSON like this one:

```
{
  "value":[
  {
    "name":{
      "first":"Bob",
      "last":"Pegelano"
  },
    "age":31,
    "email":"bob@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name":{
      "first":"Majkl",
      "last":"Skot"
    },
    "age":321,
    "email":"gecko@gmail.com"
  }]
}
```

I can easily update an array like this.

```
val jsarrayUpdate = (__ \ 'value).json.update(
  __.read[JsArray].map{ o => o :+ Json.obj( "field243" -> "coucou" ) }
)      

myJson.transform(jsarrayUpdate)
```

But I have simple array JSON without any key:

```
  [{
    "name":{
      "first":"Bob",
      "last":"Pegelano"
  },
    "age":31,
    "email":"bob@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name":{
      "first":"Majkl",
      "last":"Skot"
    },
    "age":321,
    "email":"gecko@gmail.com"
  }]
```

And was hoping to be able to edit it with this command:

```
val jsarrayUpdate2 = __.json.update(
  __.read[JsArray].map{ o => o :+ Json.obj( "field243" -> "coucou" ) }
)
```

This is not working nor is anything else I tried in the past two hours. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
jsArray.as[List[JsObject]].map {i => i ++ Json.obj( "field243" -> "coucou")}
```

This will give you a `List[JsObject]`. If you need you can convert it back to `JsArray` with

```
Json.toJson(listOfJsObjects).as[JsArray]
```

Comment: Thank you. 

While this ofcourse works, but is not using plays json transformations. I would like to learn what is going wrong in my example.